# How to disable Basic Authorization in Spring for specific super users on login

Tags: spring-boot, authorization, super

I am using Spring to build a Web Application that has a complicated authorisation system. And I am using the  @EnableWebSecurity for this purpose.

The question is, for some super users, I need the authorization system to be disabled, means allow those, and only those specific users to access everything once logged in. What should I do?

I am trying to do the following in the WebSecurityConfig Bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (loggedin user has limited access){
        //enable authorization
 http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
         .loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll().invalidateHttpSession(true);
        }else{
         //disable basic authorization
            http .authorizeRequests() .anyRequest().authenticated() .and() .formLogin() .and() .httpBasic().disable();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code is for configuring your security setup it isn't code that is called for each and every authentication.

Comment: Then this method will not be called on every login?! If so, whare I am supposed to add my check?

Comment: No it is only called once at startup to configure your security settings.